# What could be the reason why the url launcher plugin does not work?

Tags: flutter

I want to use the Url launcher plugin on my flutter page.When I click on my picture from the network, I want the Url launcher plugin to open my Pdf file, but it doesn't happen. Can you tell me the correct code?

```
new GestureDetector(
                onTap:(){ _launchURL();
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(

                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    image: new DecorationImage(
                                      image: new NetworkImage(
                                          "https://g.fmanager.net/Image/objects/1-kitaplar/evrimAldatmacasi_8b_tr.jpg"),
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  child: Transform(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    transform: Matrix4.skewY(
                                      0.0,
                                    )..rotateZ(0.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      color: Color(0x99FFFFFF),
                                      child: new Text(
                                        "Evrim Aldatmacası",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),

                  }
                }



_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open PDF file with the following code snippet
please change http://test.com/Android/sample.pdf to your pdf link location

```
Future<void> _launchInBrowser(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: false);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
...

RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _launchInBrowser("http://test.com/Android/sample.pdf");
                }),
                child: const Text('Launch in browser'),
              ),
```

execution result

[image]

Comment: this is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that by default it is using `LaunchMode.inAppWebView` mode. Please consider `launch` as deprecated.

So the answer should be

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf");
if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)){
    await launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
}
```

This open a pdf file in the right way.